# Why matplotlib is also printing data while doing a subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Hi I can t figure out how to properly use pyplot for multiple plots, in addition to the plot it also print me the full array of data

```
# import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)

fig, axes=plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2)

# the histogram of the data
axes[1,0].hist(x, 50) # kinda work, the problem is it print the array and then do the plot

plt.hist(x, 50, ax=axes[0,0]) # not wokring inner() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ax'
```

Comment: always use the axes object directly. it's just easier. `axes[0, 0].hist(...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important information you missed in the question is that you are using a Jupyter Notebook. 
In order to show a plot in a jupyter notebook you may call `plt.show()` at the end of the cell, or you may use `%matplotlib inline` backend.

If using several subplots it's best to use the oo interface, i.e. not using `plt.hist(...)` but `axes[0,2].hist(...)`. This way you directly set the axes to which to plot. (`plt.hist(..., ax=...)` does not exist - hence the error)

In order not to have the array printed **you may suppress the output from the `ax.hist()` line by using a semicolon at the end (`;`).**

```
axes[1,0].hist(x, 50);
```

Complete Example (using `plt.show()`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)

fig, axes=plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2)

# the histogram of the data
axes[1,0].hist(x, 50); 
axes[3,1].hist(x, 50);

plt.show()
```

Complete example (using inline backend):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)

fig, axes=plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2)

# the histogram of the data
axes[1,0].hist(x, 50); 
axes[3,1].hist(x, 50);
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, how did you guess the 'Jupyter Notebook'?

Comment: If something gets printed without any `print` statement or other output command suggests that there is a non-standard environment in play. Experience tells that the described behaviour is exactly reproduced in a Jupyter notebook. However, one may not always be lucky to have someone guess the solution; thus questions about undesired behaviour should always state the environment in use.

Comment: yep you were right about jupyter, thank you for the help !

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the described behaviour in

```
axes[1,0].hist(x, 50)
```

i.e. the histogram is plotted as expected and the array is not printed. In the second statement, `ax` is not a valid keyword. Instead you can set the current `axes` instance with `plt.sca()`:

```
plt.sca(axes[0,0])
plt.hist(x, 50)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: using `axes[0,0].hist(x, 50)` would be much easier

Comment: @Paul I know, but the OP wanted to know about both ways.